# The induced emf in a straight wire

Tags: induction

when I came to an explanation of the induced emf in the straight wire it shows that the wire starts its motion from the position where it is perpendicular to the magnetic field lines, like this:[image]
And the equation used to measure the induced emf is (emf=Blv sin theta)
Where theta is the angle between the direction of motion and the magnetic lines. And I was wondering how the equation would be if the wire starts the motion from a position where the angle between it and the field line is less than 90, something like this:[image]
In the figure above there are two angles: the angle between the wire and the field lines and the angle between the direction of motion and the field lines, so which angle will be involved in the equation (emf=Blv sin theta)? Or are the two angles equal each other?

Comment: You are still, I'm assuming, moving the wire _much much much_ less fast than the speed of light?

Comment: @Asmyldof What is the relation between what I ask and the speed of light? You confused me, but if you ask whether I still move the wire with the same velocity in both cases, yes the velocity is the same.

Comment: In retrospection I see in my impulse of making a point, I oversimplified. However, the electron potential travels at 2/3rd of the speed of light along a copper wire. This is a factor in deciding "how much effect" your angular movement has, as long as the same length of wire stays in the field at all times. I'm hung over though, so not much in the mood for fully working it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General form of the equation: \$ V_{Ind} = N B l v \ sin\ \theta\$

Where:

- \$ V_{Ind}\$ = Induced Voltage in V.
- \$N\$ = Number of turns - in your case 1.
- \$B\$ = Flux Density in T (Teslas = Wb/m^2).
- \$v\$ = velocity in m/s.
- \$l\$ = length in m.

Let \$ V_{MAX} = N B l v\$.

Motion can be split into two components, \$x = V_{MAX}\ cos\ \theta\$ and \$y = V_{MAX}\ sin\ \theta\$.

The x-component (\$cos\ \theta\$) would be in parallel with the magnetic field.  No flux lines are crossed, no induced EMF.  It can be ignored.

The y-component (\$sin\ \theta\$) is perpendicular to magnetic field.  It is the only component which crosses the lines of magnetic flux, so it is the component which induces the voltage by Faraday's Law.  Maximum induced voltage would occur at \$90\unicode{xb0}\$, and min at \$0\unicode{xb0}\$.

This demonstrates the how motion of a wire in a magnetic field induces a voltage.  The basis for generators.  Too get any meaningful voltage you will have to have many turns.

Now, look at your drawing and concentrate on the motion.  Horizontal movement would produce no voltage (parallel to magnetic field).  Vertical maximum.  This should help you clarify which angle \$\theta\$ or \$\theta _L\$.